# angular-dashboard-framework AutoRefresh

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm using https://github.com/angular-dashboard-framework/angular-dashboard-framework
One of our requirement is autofresh complete dashboard or currently focued tab after 15 minutes. e.g. if user is on http://angular-dashboard-framework.github.io/angular-dashboard-framework/#/sample/01 then it should be automatically refreshed after 15 minutes.

Found lot of CRUD methods to refresh html page on body load etc. Is there standard way in ADF angular-dashboard-framework to achieve this?

Comment: Would you like refresh the widget content or all dashboard?

Comment: complete dashboard. I'm able to refresh individual using $interval in .controller

Comment: Why would you like this behavior?

Comment: Client requirement :).

Comment: Did you try to using interval on div which contains dashboard?

Comment: no i didn't. Just wanted to understand correct way of doing it. Is it recommended to use interval on parent div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can try two possible solutions:

1. The first is add an interval on the dashboard controller, exactly like widget
2. Using interval on div which contains dashboard. ([Tutorial](https://codeforgeek.com/2014/09/refresh-div-angularjs-interval/))

I'm not sure that one of this solution is correct because both are not tested, but is an attempt.

Let me know and if you want contact me :)

Regards

Comment: completed with using interval on controller.. Thanks for tutorial . it's very useful

Comment: Perfect :) if the answer is your final solution, please mark it as confirmed :)